# How do we get value of field with Id using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get value of a input hidden field with an id like this

```
   leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkid
```

I tried using

```
$("#leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkid").val();
```

but thats throwing an error

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo:
>   leadConversionForm

I dont have control of how the id is been created. This is the way id is generated by salesforce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `:` with `\\:`. This is required because `:` is reserverd as it is used with selectors.

Try this:-

```
$("#leadConversionPage\\:leadConversionForm\\:pBConvertLead\\:pbSectionLeadSection\\:pbsiAccountName\\:accountLookup_lkid").val();
```

*From [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DSelectors%26redirect%3Dno)*

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

Comment: Yup. Right there.  Article on it here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/